# Reference with static type error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-builder

I have an ActionScript 3 function looking like this:

```
private function removeEntry(myT:Vector.<MyType>):void
        {
            for (var i:Number; = myT.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {   
                if(!myT[i].condition)
                {
                    removeChild(myT[i]);
                    myT.removeAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately I get the following nasty error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Call to a possibly undefined
>   method removeAt through a reference with static type
>   Vector..  (...) Flex Problem

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using flash player 19+ (or air 19+)?  It's a pretty new method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using slice instead of removeAt:

```
private function removeEntry(myT:Vector.<MyType>):void
        {
            for (var i:Number; = myT.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {   
                if(!myT[i].condition)
                {
                    removeChild(myT[i]);
                    myT.slice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```